# Pagina inicial site wordpress não aparece na lista de páginas

Tags: wordpress

Estou usando um tema wordpress mas, quando acesso **todas as paginas**, somente aparece a página **sobre**, a home(pagina inicial), não aparece na lista.

alguem sabe como resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na verdade voce esta acessando todos os posts, nao todas as paginas. Paginas sao estruturas completas do Wordpress pra simular uma pagina web normal, posts sao posts..

Comment: nao amigo, olha ali o print, acessei todas as paginas mesmo.

Comment: mas o print que vc ta mostrando do site eh de posts..

Comment: Nao cara é a pagina mesmo, olha a url,é assim que abre o site, a pagina inicial exibe posts,ela nao é estatica.

Comment: Qual o nome desse tema? Cria uns posts fake, só de teste e manda o print, se possível.

Comment: nome do tema é Rock N'Rolla

Comment: quando faço um novo post ele aparece em cima do ultimo post na pagina inicial, normal

Comment: Quando você clica no sobre, vai para algum lugar?

Comment: sim, vai pra uma pagina,ate pq sobre é a unica pagina do site la na lista de todas as paginas

Comment: Cria um botão Home na barra de menu que direcione para página que vc deseja, já que por padrão, o tema não tem.

Comment: bom isso eu ja tinha feito, mas a duvida era mesmo pq nao aparece na lista de paginas, pelo jeito vou ter que fazer isso